# How to remove array element with loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I want to delete an associative array element based on an `if/else` condition. I am unable to delete the array element. Here is my code. I just need to remove array elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var marks = $("#marks").val(); //getting student marks
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($records); ?>; // getting student record in array
    
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
      var Isstudent = item.Isstudent
      var Ismandatory = item.Ismandatory
      var minMarks = item.min_value
      var maxMarks = item.max_value
      if (Isstudent == "1") {
        if (marks <= minMarks) {
          $this - > remove();
        } else {
          $this - > remove();
        }
      }
      console.log(item);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What is `$this` supposed to be here?

Comment: Also, please present _proper_ [mre]s of such issues. In this case, that would mean showing actual example data, instead of PHP code (that no one of us here is able to execute anyway, since we lack your server-side setup & data.)

Comment: @Cbore: i dont know how to remove array element i tried with $this->remove();

Comment: Please post the value of `data`. It seems like `filter()` is all you need here, though.

Comment: Note, it's much easier to create a new array with the elements you want than to "remove" elements from an array.   As mentioned above, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) helps a long way.    `$this->remove()` looks like php code - don't mix php code inside your javascript code (in this way).

Answer (score 0):

You could just filter the data with that one condition

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit").click(function() {
    var marks = $("#marks").val(); //getting student marks
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($records); ?>; // getting student record in array
    data = data.filter(e => e.Isstudent !== 1) // any array item where Isstudent == 1 will be omitted.
    });
});
```